# Why I am getting error of "Insufficient Margin" on placing Binance API futures order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, trading, binance

```
import { createRequire, runMain } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const Binance = require("node-binance-api");
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: "<API-KEY>",
  APISECRET: "<API-SECRET>",
  useServerTime: true,
});

async function Trade(interval, { symbol, EnterAt, Type }) {
  try {
    if ((interval == "1h" || interval == "4h") & (Type == "SHORT")) {
      let response = await binance.futuresBalance();
      let pair = response.filter((el) => el.asset == "USDT");

      const leverage = 6;
      let quantity = Math.round(
        ((parseFloat(pair[0].availableBalance) * leverage) / EnterAt).toFixed(2)
      );

      let takeProfit = EnterAt - (EnterAt * 0.6) / 100;
      let stopMarket = EnterAt + (EnterAt * 1.1) / 100;

      // Adjust leverage
      let adjustLeverage = await binance.futuresLeverage(symbol, leverage);

      // Futures Market Sell
      let short = await binance.futuresMarketSell(symbol, quantity);

      // Set TAKE PROFIT
      let TP = await binance.futuresOrder("BUY", symbol, quantity, false, {
        type: "TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET",
        stopPrice: takeProfit.toFixed(2),
        closePosition: true,
      });
      // Set STOP LOSS
      let SL = await binance.futuresOrder("BUY", symbol, quantity, false, {
        type: "STOP_MARKET",
        workingType: "MARK_PRICE",
        stopPrice: stopMarket.toFixed(2),
        closePosition: true,
      });
      console.log("SHORT: ", short);
      console.log("TP: ", TP);
      console.log("SL: ", SL);
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

function wrapUpTrade(interval, { symbol, EnterAt }) {
  binance.useServerTime(() =>
    Trade(interval, { symbol: symbol, EnterAt: EnterAt })
  );
}
// wrapUpTrade("1h", { symbol: "XRPUSDT", shortAt: 0.774 });
export { wrapUpTrade };
```

This code is only for futures Market Sell (sell short). Why do I get an error of Insufficient Margin on placing an order of coin having a price of $4.5 and I have $2.9 in my wallet? On leveraging(6x) I will be having (6 * $2.9 = $17.4) that is greater than $4.5 still I get the error of Insufficient error. Function Trade takes some arguments:

```
Interval: "4h" or "1h"
symbol: "PAIR/(USDT)" // BTCUSDT, ETHUSDT
EnterAt: It is used to calculate Stoploss and TakeProfit. The type is int.
Type: "SHORT", means futuresSell
```